# How do I use what is learned from another method?

Tags: java

I want method4 to use what is learned from method3. Is that possible?

```
`public class MethodHelp {
public static void main(String[] args) 
 {
    MethodHelp main = new MethodHelp();

      System.out.println("Enter a date (use the format -> (MM/DD/YYYY)");

      //declare Scanner
      Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);

      System.out.println("Enter a month (MM): ");
      String month = in.nextLine();

      System.out.println("Enter a day (DD): ");
      String day = in.nextLine();

      System.out.println("Enter a year (YYYY): ");
      String year = in.nextLine();

    String enteredDate = month + "/" + day + "/" + year;
      //System.out.println(enteredDate);

    if (main.method1(enteredDate)) 
      {
        main.method2(month, day, year);
        main.method3(year);
        main.method4(month, day);
    }
}

private boolean method1(String enteredDate) 
 {
   //some code
}

private void method2(String month, String day, String year) 
 {
        //somecode
}

private void method3(String year) 
 {
        //somecode
}

private static void method4(String month, String day)
 {
     //somecode
}}
```

I figure I need method3 to return something back to the main method, then pass it to method4. But that seems like it won't work.

Comment: did you write method3 and method4 if so just have method 3 return whatever is "learnt" and pass this into method 4 as a variable ie. `var = main.method3(year);`  and then `main.method4(month, day, var)` what var is declared as depends on the data you'd like to pass between the two methods ... maybe some more detail would help clarrify your needs

Comment: That depends. What would you like `method3` to actually return?  Is it the `month` or `day`?

Comment: method3 checks if the year is a certain type of year. I need that information (whether if the year is a certain year) in method4.

if i were to return something from method3, what would i have to include?

Comment: if it is a certain year (eg. leap year) have method three return a boolean set to true or false and then pass into method 4 as specified, in my first comment

Comment: @brendanmorrison do i have to define a boolean in main and pass it to method3 beforehand? or can i define that in method3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for

code your `method3` to return year, and add one more parameter to your `method4` to accept a year.

```
private String method3(String year) 
{
   //some calculations
   return year;  
}

main.method4(month, day,main.method3(year));
```

Comment: this solution is essentially equivalent to what i proposed in comments

Comment: @brendanmorrison ok, sorry, I didn't read your comment, so you can put your comments as answer then I will delete my answer and upvote you answer

Comment: no worries at all your answer works we can just leave it (just clarrifying for @DwellingPlace) as they seems new to java and did not want to confuse them

Comment: when i compile, i get the error (using your idea):
"cannot return a value from method whose result type is void"

is it because i parsed the year into an integer?
    theYear = Integer.parseInt(year);

Comment: @DwellingPlace your method is giving you an error because its return type is void, you need to set return type to the datatype which is returned by the method

Comment: @Bhushan how would i do that?

Comment: @DwellingPlace take a look at my answer where `method3` returns `year` which has `String` datatype, so it is declared as `private String method3(String year)`

Comment: @Bhushan O I see. instead of a String, i used boolean and passed that to method4. I needed to do one thing or another based on what method3 calculated. :)
Thanks!